# Equivalent of `type -a` in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to build my PowerShell troubleshooting skills, and I was hoping to find a similar tool to `type` in bash.

Example usage of `type`:

```
17:07 Mac Shell: Git/>$ type -a shell_session_save
shell_session_save is a function
shell_session_save () 
{ 
    if [ -n "$SHELL_SESSION_FILE" ]; then
        echo -n 'Saving session...';
        ( umask 077;
        echo 'echo Restored session: "$(date -r '$(date +%s)')"' >|"$SHELL_SESSION_FILE" );
        declare -F shell_session_save_user_state > /dev/null && shell_session_save_user_state;
        shell_session_history_allowed && shell_session_save_history;
        echo 'completed.';
    fi
}
17:07 Mac Shell: Git/>$
```

I just want an easy way to view function code in PowerShell's CLI.  Is this possible natively?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you mean 'output content of a function'? If that's what you mean, it is `Get-Content Function:\functionname`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is available natively using `Get-Command` as such:

```
Get-Command MyFunctionName -ShowCommandInfo
```

Here's the output of one of my functions that I keep on hand named `Get-OutputFilePath`:

```
Name          : Get-OutputFilePath
ModuleName    : 
Module        : @{Name=}
CommandType   : Function
Definition    : 
                [CmdletBinding()]
                Param(
                    [String]$Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*",
                    [String]$InitialDirectory,
                    [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName,ValueFromPipeline)]
                    [Alias('DefaultFileName')]
                    [String]$FullName,
                    [Switch]$Force)
                    BEGIN{
                        [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms")
                    }
                    PROCESS{
                        If($FullName -match "\\.+$" -and !$InitialDirectory){$InitialDirectory = Split-Path $FullName;$FullName = Split-Path $FullName -Leaf}ElseIf(!$InitialDirectory){$InitialDirectory=[Environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop')}
                        $SaveFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog
                        $SaveFileDialog.initialDirectory = $InitialDirectory
                        Try{$SaveFileDialog.filter = $Filter}Catch{Throw $_;Break}
                        $SaveFileDialog.FileName = $FullName
                        $SaveFileDialog.OverwritePrompt = !$Force
                        If($SaveFileDialog.ShowDialog() -eq "OK"){$SaveFileDialog.FileName}
                    }

ParameterSets : {@{Name=__AllParameterSets; IsDefault=False; Parameters=System.Management.Automation.PSObject[]}}
```